# Heroku Deployment : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_summernote'

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, gunicorn, summernote

During the deployment for my python django blog app, this happening keeps continuing! so I don't know how to deal with it anymore. Actually I've found the sticking error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_summernote'`.

I solved many previous errors, h10, h14 but the `ModuleNotFoundError` still exists.

in my Installed App in `setting.py`, it doesn't have any problem with it.
So I couldn't catch up..

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'articles',
    'templates',
    'django_summernote',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'gunicorn',
]
```

**and below is the Error part**

```
State changed from crashed to starting
2018-12-10T13:25:48.417441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn djangoblog.wsgi:application --log-file - --log-level debug`
2018-12-10T13:25:48.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553811+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 13:25:51 +0000] [4] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553836+00:00 app[web.1]: config: None
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553838+00:00 app[web.1]: bind: ['0.0.0.0:47277']
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553839+00:00 app[web.1]: backlog: 2048
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553841+00:00 app[web.1]: workers: 2
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553842+00:00 app[web.1]: worker_class: sync
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553844+00:00 app[web.1]: threads: 1
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553845+00:00 app[web.1]: worker_connections: 1000
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553847+00:00 app[web.1]: max_requests: 0
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553848+00:00 app[web.1]: max_requests_jitter: 0
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553850+00:00 app[web.1]: timeout: 30
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553851+00:00 app[web.1]: graceful_timeout: 30
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553852+00:00 app[web.1]: keepalive: 2
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553854+00:00 app[web.1]: limit_request_line: 4094
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553855+00:00 app[web.1]: limit_request_fields: 100
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553857+00:00 app[web.1]: limit_request_field_size: 8190
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553858+00:00 app[web.1]: reload: False
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553859+00:00 app[web.1]: reload_engine: auto
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553861+00:00 app[web.1]: reload_extra_files: []
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553862+00:00 app[web.1]: spew: False
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553864+00:00 app[web.1]: check_config: False
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553865+00:00 app[web.1]: preload_app: False
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553866+00:00 app[web.1]: sendfile: None
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553868+00:00 app[web.1]: reuse_port: False
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553869+00:00 app[web.1]: chdir: /app
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553871+00:00 app[web.1]: daemon: False
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553872+00:00 app[web.1]: raw_env: []
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553873+00:00 app[web.1]: pidfile: None
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553875+00:00 app[web.1]: worker_tmp_dir: None
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553876+00:00 app[web.1]: user: 50242
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553878+00:00 app[web.1]: group: 50242
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553879+00:00 app[web.1]: umask: 0
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553880+00:00 app[web.1]: initgroups: False
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553882+00:00 app[web.1]: tmp_upload_dir: None
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553900+00:00 app[web.1]: secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553902+00:00 app[web.1]: forwarded_allow_ips: ['*']
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553904+00:00 app[web.1]: accesslog: -
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553905+00:00 app[web.1]: disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553907+00:00 app[web.1]: access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553908+00:00 app[web.1]: errorlog: -
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553909+00:00 app[web.1]: loglevel: debug
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553911+00:00 app[web.1]: capture_output: False
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553912+00:00 app[web.1]: logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553914+00:00 app[web.1]: logconfig: None
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553915+00:00 app[web.1]: logconfig_dict: {}
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553917+00:00 app[web.1]: syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553918+00:00 app[web.1]: syslog: False
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553919+00:00 app[web.1]: syslog_prefix: None
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553921+00:00 app[web.1]: syslog_facility: user
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553923+00:00 app[web.1]: enable_stdio_inheritance: False
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553924+00:00 app[web.1]: statsd_host: None
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553925+00:00 app[web.1]: statsd_prefix:
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553927+00:00 app[web.1]: proc_name: None
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553928+00:00 app[web.1]: default_proc_name: djangoblog.wsgi:application
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553930+00:00 app[web.1]: pythonpath: None
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553931+00:00 app[web.1]: paste: None
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553933+00:00 app[web.1]: on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7facbfe22268>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553934+00:00 app[web.1]: on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7facbfe22378>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553936+00:00 app[web.1]: when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7facbfe22488>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553937+00:00 app[web.1]: pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7facbfe22598>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553939+00:00 app[web.1]: post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7facbfe226a8>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553940+00:00 app[web.1]: post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7facbfe227b8>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553942+00:00 app[web.1]: worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7facbfe228c8>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553943+00:00 app[web.1]: worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7facbfe229d8>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553945+00:00 app[web.1]: pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7facbfe22ae8>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553946+00:00 app[web.1]: pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7facbfe22bf8>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553948+00:00 app[web.1]: post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7facbfe22c80>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553949+00:00 app[web.1]: child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7facbfe22d90>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553950+00:00 app[web.1]: worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7facbfe22ea0>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553952+00:00 app[web.1]: nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7facbfe2f048>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553953+00:00 app[web.1]: on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7facbfe2f158>
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553955+00:00 app[web.1]: proxy_protocol: False
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553956+00:00 app[web.1]: proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553958+00:00 app[web.1]: keyfile: None
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553959+00:00 app[web.1]: certfile: None
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553961+00:00 app[web.1]: ssl_version: 2
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553962+00:00 app[web.1]: cert_reqs: 0
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553963+00:00 app[web.1]: ca_certs: None
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553965+00:00 app[web.1]: suppress_ragged_eofs: True
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553966+00:00 app[web.1]: do_handshake_on_connect: False
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553968+00:00 app[web.1]: ciphers: TLSv1
2018-12-10T13:25:51.553977+00:00 app[web.1]: raw_paste_global_conf: []
2018-12-10T13:25:51.554464+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 13:25:51 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2018-12-10T13:25:51.560899+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 13:25:51 +0000] [4] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
2018-12-10T13:25:51.561173+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 13:25:51 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:47277 (4)
2018-12-10T13:25:51.561349+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 13:25:51 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2018-12-10T13:25:51.570108+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 13:25:51 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2018-12-10T13:25:51.610234+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 13:25:51 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2018-12-10T13:25:51.704389+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 13:25:51 +0000] [4] [DEBUG] 2 workers
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856398+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 22:25:52 +0900] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856447+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856450+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856452+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856453+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856455+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856456+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856458+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856459+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856461+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856463+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856464+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856466+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856467+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856469+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856470+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856473+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/djangoblog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856474+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856476+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856477+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856479+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856480+00:00 app[web.1]: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856482+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856483+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856485+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856486+00:00 app[web.1]: module = import_module(entry)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856488+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856489+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856497+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_summernote'
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856514+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 22:25:52 +0900] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856516+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856517+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856519+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856521+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856522+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856524+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856525+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856527+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856528+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856529+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856531+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856532+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856534+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856535+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856536+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856538+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/djangoblog/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856539+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856541+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856542+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856544+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856545+00:00 app[web.1]: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856546+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856548+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856549+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856551+00:00 app[web.1]: module = import_module(entry)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856552+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856553+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856590+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_summernote'
2018-12-10T13:25:52.856988+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 22:25:52 +0900] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2018-12-10T13:25:52.857183+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 22:25:52 +0900] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2018-12-10T13:25:53.034230+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 13:25:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2018-12-10T13:25:53.034673+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 13:25:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2018-12-10T13:25:52.898067+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-12-10T13:25:53.175315+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2018-12-10T13:25:53.196695+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

**Procfile**

`web: gunicorn djangoblog.wsgi:application --log-file - --log-level debug`

Comment: Make sure that `django-summernote` is in your `requirements.txt`/`pipenv` file, and that you have the latest version checked in.

Comment: Thank you Alasdair. After `py -m pip freeze > requirements.txt` then, push through Git, It works perfectly!

Answer (score -2):

This type of error occurs only when you declared the path in urls.py file but  don’t declared the function in views.py file. Be sure you have followed these steps:
 1. Register your app in setting.py file
 2. Declared path in urls.py file (In project directry)
 3. Declared path in urls.py file (In your app directry)
 4.Declared the def (function) in views.py file